# Find out physical network adapter

Tags: winapi, network-programming

With PowerShell I can find out all physical network adapters with:

```
Get-NetAdapter -Physical
```

Is there a similiar function in the Win32 API?

I have called

```
GetAdaptersAddresses
```

to get information about my installed network adapters.
But the returned struct IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES have no info about physical adapters.
How can I find it out?

Comment: Have you checked Simon's answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Network Configuration Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/network/ff559080(v=vs.85)) API, like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Netcfgx.h>
#include <devguid.h>

int main()
{
  INetCfg* cfg = nullptr;
  IEnumNetCfgComponent* components = nullptr;

  // TOTO: HRESULT checks omitted to be added
  auto hr = CoInitialize(nullptr);
  hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CNetCfg, nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&cfg));
  hr = cfg->Initialize(nullptr);
  hr = cfg->EnumComponents(&GUID_DEVCLASS_NET, &components);
  do
  {
    INetCfgComponent* component = nullptr;
    hr = components->Next(1, &component, nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hr) || !component)
      break;

    DWORD characteristics = 0;
    component->GetCharacteristics(&characteristics);
    if ((characteristics & NCF_PHYSICAL) == NCF_PHYSICAL)
    {
      LPWSTR name = nullptr;
      component->GetDisplayName(&name);
      wprintf(L"%s 0x%08X\n", name, characteristics);
      if (name)
      {
        CoTaskMemFree(name);
      }
    }
    
    component->Release();

  } while (true);

  hr = cfg->Uninitialize();
  components->Release();
  cfg->Release();

  CoUninitialize();
  return 0;
}
```

Or you can use WMI with [Win32_NetworkAdapter class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapter) as it has a boolean `PhysicalAdapter` property.

Or you can use WinRT and query for [NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.networkadapter.ianainterfacetype), like this in C#:

```
foreach (var profile in Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles())
{
    Console.WriteLine(profile.ProfileName + " type:" + profile.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType);
}
```